# Pytorch both arguments to matmul need to be at least 1D, but they are 0D and 2D

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am trying to learn pytorch and reinforcemnent learning with the library. I dont really understand about batch size and keep getting this error message "both arguments to matmul need to be at least 1D, but they are 0D and 2D"

Here is my code so far

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import torch as T
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.distributions import Categorical
import torch.optim as optim


class network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lr, input_dims, h1_dims, h2_dims, n_actions):
        super(network, self).__init__()

        self.lr = lr
        self.input_dims = input_dims
        self.h1_dims = h1_dims
        self.h2_dims = h2_dims
        self.n_actions = n_actions

        self.h1 = nn.Linear(self.input_dims, self.h1_dims)
        self.h2 = nn.Linear(self.h1_dims, self.h2_dims)
        self.p = nn.Linear(self.h2_dims, self.n_actions)
        self.v = nn.Linear(self.h2_dims, 1)

        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
        self.device = T.device('cuda:0' if T.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.to(self.device)

    def forward(self, observation):
        state = T.tensor(observation, dtype=T.float).to(self.device)

        x = F.relu(self.h1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.h2(x))
        v = self.v(x)
        p = F.softmax(self.p(x), dim=0)

        return v, p



class agent(object):

      def __init__(self, n_actions):

            self.gamma = 0.99
            self.n_actions = n_actions
            self.log_probs = None
            self.network = network(lr=0.005, input_dims=4, h1_dims=128,
                  h2_dims=128, n_actions=self.n_actions)


      def choose_action(self, observation):

              value, policy = self.network(observation)

              action_probs = T.distributions.Categorical(probs=policy)
              action = action_probs.sample()
              log_probs = action_probs.log_prob(action)
              self.log_probs = log_probs
              return action.numpy()


      def learn(self, state, reward, new_state, done):
              self.network.optimizer.zero_grad()

              curr_state = np.array(state)
              next_state = np.array(new_state)
              value_current = self.network.forward(T.from_numpy(curr_state))
              value_next = self.network.forward(T.from_numpy(next_state))
              reward = T.tensor(reward, dtype=T.float).to(self.network.device)
              delta = reward + self.gamma*value_next[0]*(1-int(done)) - value_current[0]

              actor_loss = -self.log_probs * delta
              critic_loss = delta**2

              (actor_loss + critic_loss).backward()
              self.network.optimizer.step()




env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')

action_spaces = env.action_space.n

create_agent = agent(action_spaces)
score_history = []
num_episodes = 1

for i in range(num_episodes):
    done = False
    score = 0
    observation = env.reset()
    while not done:
        action = create_agent.choose_action(observation[0])
        observation_, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        create_agent.learn(observation[0], reward, observation_, done)
        observation = observation_
        score += reward

        #print(learn)
    score_history.append(score)
    print('episode ', i, 'score %.2f' % score )
```

This is the error message

> Exception has occurred: RuntimeError both arguments to matmul need to
> be at least 1D, but they are 0D and 2D   File
> "D:\kuliah\RL\policy_gradient2\testing.py", line 33, in forward
> x = F.relu(self.h1(state))   File "D:\kuliah\RL\policy_gradient2\testing.py", line 55, in choose_action
> value, policy = self.network(observation)   File "D:\kuliah\RL\policy_gradient2\testing.py", line 96, in 
> action = create_agent.choose_action(observation[0]) RuntimeError: both arguments to matmul need to be at least 1D, but they are 0D and
> 2D

Comment: Please post full error stacktrace

Comment: Hi, I already edit the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you give `observation[0]` as an input for the network in `action = create_agent.choose_action(observation[0])`, you create a zero-dimensional tensor in the forward method of the network here `state = T.tensor(observation, dtype=T.float).to(self.device)`.

Pytorch models expects the inputs to be at least one dimensional as stated in the error message.
You can overcome this error by `action = create_agent.choose_action(np.array([observation[0]]))` in your while loop, but this a runtime error as the network expects the input to have shape [batch_size, input_dim] which is 4 in your case. I don't know why are trying to give 'observation[0]' as an input to the network which has incorrect shape ([1, 1]).